# React image gallery with magnify effect like Amazon

Tags: reactjs, zooming, preview, image-gallery

I try to combine `react-image-gallery` with `react-image-magnify` to get gallery with magnify preview effect and according to `react-image-gallery` docs I am passing `MyReactImageMagnify` component to the `renderItem` prop on the `ImageGallery` component but there is no magnified image on the right side.

Here is how the gallery with magnify should look like [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-MicroSD-Adapter-MB-ME128GA-AM/dp/B06XWZWYVP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWZWYVP)

And here is the codesandbox with what I have so far https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lumiere-gk1y1

```
class MyImageGallery extends Component {
  myRenderItem() {
    return <MyReactImageMagnify {...this.props} />;
  }

  render() {
    const properties = {
      thumbnailPosition: "left",
      useBrowserFullscreen: false,
      showPlayButton: false,
      renderItem: this.myRenderItem.bind(this),
      items: [
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/1",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/1"
        },
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/2",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/2"
        },
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/3",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/3"
        }
      ]
    };

    return <ImageGallery {...properties} />;
  }
}
```

Edit: Amazon is just for illustration of "magnify to the right". I made another codesandbox with 2 columns grid, you can see how plain `<MyReactImageMagnify />` component works and `<MyImageGallery />` doesn't. https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-browser-0dbyo

Comment: Do you want to image preview to be fixed, or variable size like Amazon? Fixed would be much easier if that's all you need

Comment: Fixed size is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is with an element overflow. The gallery uses an `overflow: hidden` to hide the not visible slides, so the zoomed image is also hidden.

The good thing about `react-image-magnify` is that you can specify a portal where you want to render the large image.

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-rosalind-g9ve4

Create a new div with an id, where you want the large image to be displayed:

```
<Grid container spacing={4}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <MyImageGallery />
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2} item xs={6} direction="column">
    <Grid item>
      <div id="myPortal" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Each element of the gallery will be a ReactImageMagnify component, with the portal id as a property:

```
<ReactImageMagnify
  {...{
    smallImage: {
      alt: "Wristwatch by Ted Baker London",
      isFluidWidth: true,
      src: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"
    },
    largeImage: {
      src: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any",
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    },
    enlargedImagePortalId: "myPortal"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I inspected the image in the link you provided and found this element:

```
<div
    id="magnifierLens"
    style="position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/apparel/rcxgs/tile._CB483369105_.gif&quot;); cursor: pointer; width: 300px; height: 316px; left: 184px; top: 169px;">
</div>
```

Which is for the blue overlay over the image and then the preview is just an absolute `div` containing the original unsized image. The image in the preview is positioned similarly to the magnifier lens.

From here, you'd need to get the proportions for the image overlay, and the image preview.

It looks like what Amazon did was hold the dimensions of the product information element:
[image: Amazon product page with 'product information element' highlighted with a red box]

In order to hold the dimensions, you would need to attach a `resize` event listener to the window

```
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize); // onWindowResize function would get new component size and update child sizes
```

You would then keep track of the mouse position over the image:

```
previewImageElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove); // onMouseMove function would update the position of the image overlay, and zoomed image
```

Once you have all of your handlers and listeners set up, you can calculate some sizes and implement them.

Here is some psuedocode for calculating the sizes:

```
 // Amazons zoom frame has a max size, and it will shrink to fit the zoomed image
const imageOverlayWidth = Math.Max(zoomedFrameWidth / zoomedImageWidth, 1) * imagePreviewWidth;
const imageOverlayWidth = Math.Max(zoomedFrameHeight / zoomedImageHeight, 1) * imagePreviewHeight;
```

`zoomedImageHeight` and `zoomedImageWidth` are the natural dimensions of the image.

Calculating `zoomedFrameWidth` and `zoomedFrameHeight` will depend on how responsive you want your preview to be. I would personally be okay with max sizes, but no shrink to fit.

```
zoomedFrameWidth = productInfoContainerWidth * 0.5;
zoomedFrameHeight = productInfoContainerHeight;
```

That should be enough to tie together a nice image preview zoom like Amazon's. Let me know if anything needs clarification as it is mostly just ideas and psuedocode.

Comment: `react-image-magnify` should do that, see my edit in the question with another codesandbox.